# Unable to Connect to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I installed SQL Server 2008 on a PC with xxx.xxx.x.200. When I connected to the server from another machine(say xxx.xxx.x.81) using SQL Server Management Studio, I get the following error.

> ```
>   TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
> ------------------------------
>
> Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Database 28 cannot be autostarted during server shutdown or startup.
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 904)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=09.00.3042&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=904&LinkId=20476

To know more, I tried the same with another client machine (say xxx.xxx.x.92), it works well. WHY does it behave like this.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old - hoping you solved your issue long before now... Assuming that you have not, I'd say to try the following:

1.) Check client xxx.xxx.x.81 to ensure that it has the proper ODBC drivers set-up for SQL Server (Control Panel -> type "ODBC" in the search box in the top right -> hit "Set up ODBC data sources..."

If not, set it up and try to reconnect. If they are set-up properly, move on to step 2...

2.) Connect from the client that is working and run a DBCC CHECKDB against "Database 28" to ensure that it's not a weird issue with the DB itself

[Microsoft says that event error 904 is not logged...](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors?view=sql-server-2017) so, you'll have to set something up manually to get feedback on the error from the server.

3.) Finally, (this may go without saying considering the age of the post) try upgrading the server to a newer, supported version (if you have not already.) Also, update your SSMS version.

Report back with any progress or further issues?